# Using java to generating XML with specific DTD declarations

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need to generate a XML file that contains specific XML Declarations and DTD declarations as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//CompanyName//DTD CompanyName PaymentService v2//EN"
"http://dtd.CompanyName.com/paymentService_v2.dtd">
```

The remaining XML to be generated also has a specific Elements and associated values.

I was wondering what would be the best way to generate this XML within my java class? Using String Buffer or DOM? Any suggestions with an example or sample code will be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the Java `DOM` API. Dealing with XML or XHTML in `String` objects is notoriously time consuming and buggy, so try and use a propper parser like `DOM` whenever you have the option to.

The below code should add a doc type and your xml declaration using Java `DOM`. The `<?xml...` should be added to the top automatically when the `DocumentBuilder` creates your document.

```
    // Create document
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.newDocument();
    //Create doc type
    DOMImplementation domImpl = doc.getImplementation();
    DocumentType doctype = domImpl.createDocumentType("paymentService", "-//CompanyName//DTD CompanyName PaymentService v2//EN", "http://dtd.CompanyName.com/paymentService_v2.dtd");
    doc.appendChild(doctype);
    // Add root element
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("root");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);
```

The XML created by the above should look like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//CompanyName//DTD CompanyName PaymentService v2//EN" "http://dtd.CompanyName.com/paymentService_v2.dtd"> 
<root>
</root>
```

A great many of the methods used in the code above can throw a large number and variety of exceptions, so make sure your exception handling is up to scratch. I hope this helps.

- Link to the [Official DOM API Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html)

Comment: thanks for your prompt and detailed response. Will implement it now and let you know in case any issues.

Comment: will this validate the generated XML against the specified DTD as well? How does the validation aspect works? thx

Comment: @GlobalDictator - Although I imagine it does, I wouldn't know how you went about viewing any generated errors from failed validation etc. I would have to do a little experimenting to work that out.

Comment: Using Transformer results in the DOCTYPE tag missing completely, so had to use XMLSerializer instead to write the results to a file.

Comment: @GlobalDictator - In which case, I'll remove that from the answer just so it's technically correct.